# How do I create binding to C function to Dart with `unsigned char**` data?

Tags: dart, ffi

0

I want to create binding to this C function in dart:

```c
int readBufferGeneral(unsigned int address, unsigned char** data, int* size, int quantity, int timeout, const char* str);
```

Dart:

```dart
typedef readBufferGeneralNative = Int32 Function(
    Uint32 address,
    Pointer<Pointer<Utf8>> data,
    Pointer<Int32> size,
    Int32 quantity,
    Int32 timeout,
    Pointer<Utf8> str);
```

DLL Lookup

```dart
final readBufferGeneral = dylib.lookupFunction<readBufferGeneralNative, ?????? >('readBufferGeneral');
```

The question is how to define in lookupFunction and how to call and malloc the desired space for variable?

I'm using c# before and the solution is:

```cs
[DllImport("dllName", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int readBufferGeneral(uint address, out IntPtr data, out int size, int quantity, int timeout, StringBuilder str);

IntPtr gData;
int gSize = 0;
int resultTest = readBufferGeneral(0, out gData, out gSize, 512, 500, new StringBuilder(driveName));
byte[] data = new byte[gSize];
Marshal.Copy(gData, data, 0, gSize);
```

Thank you!

```dart
 typedef ReadBufferGeneral = int Function(Uint32 address, Pointer<Pointer<Utf8>> data, Pointer<Int32> size, Int32 quantity, Int32 timeout, Pointer<Utf8> str);
//unsigned int address, int iterations, unsigned char** data, int* size, const char* str
typedef readBufferGeneralNative = Int32 Function(
    Uint32 address,
    Pointer<Pointer<Utf8>> data,
    Pointer<Int32> size,
    Int32 quantity,
    Int32 timeout,
    Pointer<Utf8> str);
```